# Drupal views PHP filter is showing node id instead of value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to print the taxonomy terms (which is field_company) but it's printing node id of that article.

These are my [available variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8fex.jpg)

**code used in Global: PHP**

```
<?php
$term = $row->field_company;
print($term);
?>
```

In my view **Auto Preview**, its showing like below.

> ---
>
> **article 1** Title
>
> **PHP:** 2345 //these are node ids
>
> ---
>
> **article 2** Title
>
> **PHP:** 2346 //these are node ids
>
> ---
>
> **article 3** Title
>
> **PHP:** 2347 //these are node ids
>
> ---
>
> **article 4** Title
>
> **PHP:** 2348 //these are node ids
>
> ---

What I'm expecting here is:
for example in my taxonomy list (**company**) I have terms like,

```
company taxonomy terms list
-term1
-term2
-term3
```

> ---
>
> **article 1** Title
>
> **PHP:** term1
>
> ---
>
> **article 2** Title
>
> **PHP:** term2
>
> ---
>
> **article 3** Title
>
> **PHP:** term2
>
> ---
>
> **article 4** Title
>
> **PHP:** term3
>
> ---
>
> **article 5** Title
>
> **PHP:** term1
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

If the field field_company is a taxonomy reference field, then below should work.

```
$tid = $row->field_company;
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
print($term->name);
```

But you say it is outputting a node id? Which means field_company is not a taxonomy term reference field, maybe it is a node reference field?
If it is referencing a node, then this may work.

```
$nid = $row->field_company;
$n = node_load($nid);
print($n->title);
```

Or you could use the entity api to load the term or node.

**But**,
you really should not be doing this with a Global:PHP field (in fact you should probably never use Global:PHP).
The output you want should be easy to achived in views (relationshiips) without using the Global:PHP field and will likely be faster and easier to change later if need be.

Comment: I have a situation where every user has a company name field in his account which load form the SESSION in drupal.
I want these company names to automatically populate themselves in the taxonomy vocabulary list. (If company is vocabulary all the company names from SESSION should populate as terms under that vocabulary). It should not duplicate is 2 or more users have same company.

I really have no idea if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the view object to collect your result,

Just take your field above global PHP and use foreach to get the term name :

```
<?php 
foreach($view->result as $k => $value){
print $value->field_field_company[0]['rendered']['#title'];
}
?>
```

Note- use isset if your field is not required.else you get errors.

Comment: Views Php Filter code:

`if((($_SESSION['webauth']['company']) == "xyz company")&&($data->field_field_company_name[0]['rendered']['#markup'] == "xyz taxonomy"))
return TRUE;`

I'm trying to eliminate that row which is TRUE. so that remaining will print. But this is not working in the filter code. Instead if I give it in FIELDS, (global PHP) `<?php if((($_SESSION['webauth']['company']) == "xyz company")&&($data->field_field_company_name[0]['rendered']['#markup'] == "xyz taxonomy")) echo "hi"; ?>` It works there.

Comment: You can direct use **print** function to display your fields else you leave as blank so it auto eliminated.

Comment: As of my knowledge in Views PHP filter, we cannot print. If the condition returns TRUE that particular row is eliminated from display.